# Getting error in my code snippet in o.P1 property .NET Code ERROR MESSAGE

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

```
namespace properties
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main1()
        {
            Class1 o = new Class1();

            // o.SetI(1000);
            // Console.WriteLine(o.i);
            // Console.WriteLine(o.GetI());
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Class1 o = new Class1();

            o.P1 = 10;      
            Console.WriteLine(o.P1);
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        // private  int i;

        // public void SetI(int VALUE)
        // {
        //      if (VALUE < 100)
        //         i = VALUE;
        //     else
        // }

        // public int  GetI() 
        // { 
        //     return i;
        // } 

        private int p1;    // variable
        private int P1     // Property name 
        {
            get { return p1; }
            set
            {
                if (value < 100)
                    p1 = value;
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("invalid p1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Build .net project

```
readonly struct System.Int32
```

represents a 32-bit signed integer.

> CS0122: 'Class1.P1' is inaccessible due to its protection level

This is the error displayed in the message in my code regarding  access specifiers.

How can I fix this?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You've explicitly made `Class1.P1` private. That means you can't access it from `Program`. If you want to access it from other types, you'll need to make it public or internal.

Answer (score 1):

The Property `P1` is marked as `private` and therefore can't be accessed from code outside of the `class Class1` scope. To fix this, set the protection level of the Property `P1` to `public`

Here is the edited code that should work:

```cs
namespace properties
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main1()
        {
            Class1 o = new Class1();

            // o.SetI(1000);
            // Console.WriteLine(o.i);
            //  Console.WriteLine(o.GetI());

        }


        static void Main()
        {
            Class1 o = new Class1();

            o.P1 = 10;
            Console.WriteLine(o.P1);
        }


    }

    public class Class1

    {
        // private  int i;

        // public void SetI(int VALUE)
        //  {
        //      if (VALUE < 100)
        //         i = VALUE;
        //     else
        //   }



        //  public int  GetI() 
        // { 
        //   return i;
        //  } 

        private int p1;//variable
        public int P1//Property name 
        {
            set
            {
                if (value < 100)
                    p1 = value;

                else
                    Console.WriteLine("invalalid p1");
            }

            get
            {
                return p1;
            }
        }


    }
}
```